# mysqld Settings in my.cnf not Being Applied When Executing mysql

Tags: mysql, macos

`mysql` is ignoring the settings under `[mysqld]` in `my.cnf`, it picks up the settings for `[client]` and `[mysql]`.

How do I fix this?

I tried `brew services mysql restart`, but it didn't make a difference.

#### my.cnf:

```
 λ cat /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[client]
user = <user>
host = <hostname>
port = 3306

[mysql]
auto-rehash

[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout =  28800
net_read_timeout =  28800
connect_timeout =  28800
net_write_timeout =  28800
```

Output does not show any of the settings under `[mysqld]`:

```
 λ mysql --print-defaults
mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--user=<user> --host=<hostname> --port=3306 --auto-rehash
```

Comment: And if you ask the database server, `mysqld`, for its defaults? `mysqld --print-defaults`

Comment: @Kusalananda I get the right stuff when I executed that command. I also changed the variables on the server to be 28800, this used to work fine. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

You will see two lines such as:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Check that there is no overriding in the listed files.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I  got `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` before the homebrew one, but when I ls'd them they don't exist. I copied my homebrew `my.cnf` to `/etc` then deleted it, ran `mysql` and it still loses connection after 1 min, I have all the server timeout variables to 28800 as well. On a gui app like `Datagrip` I never lose connection.